# How to determine if my laptop has heat damage?

Tags: laptop, troubleshooting, temperature, overheating

Yesterday I was running a video on my laptop, closed the lid and shoved it into its case and into my backpack. Seems like the video may have kept the laptop from sleeping properly, and it was scorching hot when I took it out an hour and a half later - too hot to touch all over the body of the laptop, though I didn't get a temperature measurement. I haven't seen any obvious signs of damage yet, but I know that heat can reduce the lifespan of batteries and I worry that there are other ways in which I may have harmed my computer.

a) What kind of problems could I have caused with overheating?
b) What would the signs to look out for be?
c) How likely is it that the laptop would sustain damage that isn't obvious but will manifest itself in subtle performance decreases, or issues that appear later on in its life?

Laptop is an HP Spectre x360 13" that I bought new this summer, in case it matters.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how long this went on for. This happened to me on an older ThinkPad when the mouse woke it up. It was like this for about 30 minutes. I let it cool down, restarted it and there was not any damage. If your machine is working properly, it is likely fine